# Explanation needed for tee, process substitution, redirect...and different behaviors in Bash and Z shell ('zsh')

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh, tee

Recently in my work, I am facing an interesting problem regarding [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) and process substitution.

Let's start with examples:

I have three little scripts:

```
$ head *.sh
```

#### File *one.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "one starts"
if [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then
    echo "$(cat /dev/stdin) from one"
else
    echo "no stdin"
fi
```

#### File *two.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "two starts"
if [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then
    echo "$(cat /dev/stdin) from two"
else
    echo "no stdin"
fi
```

#### File *three.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "three starts"
if [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then
    sed 's/^/stdin for three: /' /dev/stdin
else
    echo "no stdin"
fi
```

- All three scripts read from [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) and print something to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29).
- The `one.sh` and `two.sh` are quite similar, but the `three.sh` is a bit different. It just adds some prefix to show what it reads from the standard input.

Now I am going to execute two commands:

1: `echo "hello" | tee >(./one.sh) >(./two.sh) | ./three.sh`

2: `echo "hello" | tee >(./one.sh) >(./two.sh) >(./three.sh) >/dev/null`

First in Bash and then in Z shell (`zsh`).

### Bash (GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1))

```
$ echo "hello" | tee >(./one.sh) >(./two.sh) |./three.sh

three starts
stdin for three: hello
stdin for three: one starts
stdin for three: two starts
stdin for three: hello from two
stdin for three: hello from one
```

- Why are the outputs of `one.sh` and `two.sh` mixed with the origin "hello" and passed to `three.sh`? I expected to see the output of one and two in standard output and only the `"hello"` is going to pass to `three.sh`.

Now the other command:

```
$ echo "hello" | tee >(./one.sh) >(./two.sh) >(./three.sh) >/dev/null

one starts
two starts
three starts
stdin for three: hello
hello from two
hello from one
<---!!!note here I don't have prompt unless I press Enter or Ctrl-c)
```

- I redirect all standard output to */dev/null*. Why do I see all output from all process substitution this time? Does it seem this behavior conflict with the one above?
- Why don't I have the prompt after having executed the command?
- Why does the command start in order one->two->three, but outputs come in 3->2->1? Even if I added `sleep 3` in `three.sh`, **the output is always 3-2-1**. I know it should have something to do with standard input blocking, but I'd learn the exact reason.

### Zsh (zsh 5.8 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu))

Both commands,

```
echo "hello" | tee >(./one.sh) >(./two.sh) >(./three.sh) >/dev/null
echo "hello" | tee >(./one.sh) >(./two.sh) |./three.sh
```

Give the expected result:

```
one starts
three starts
two starts
hello from two
hello from one
stdin for three: hello
```

- It works as expected. **But the order of the output is random**, it seems that Z shell does something non-blocking here, and the order of the output is dependent on how long each script has been running. What exactly leads to the result?

Comment: IMO, they are pretty different and merit an individual discussion. Hence you really should make this diferent questions.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> echo "hello"|tee >(./one.sh) >(./two.sh) |./three.sh
> ```

There are two possible order of operations for the `tee` part of the pipeline

#### First

1. Redirect standard output to a pipe that's connected to `./three.sh`'s standard input.
2. Set up the pipes and subprocesses for the command substitutions. They inherit the same redirected standard output pipe used by `tee`.
3. Execute `tee`.

#### Second

1. Set up the pipes and subprocesses for the the command substitutions. They share the same default standard output - to the terminal.
2. Redirect `tee`'s standard output to a pipe that's connected to `./three.sh`'s standard input. This redirection doesn't affect the pipes set up in step 1.
3. Execute `tee`.

`bash` uses the first set of operations, `zsh` uses the second. In both cases, the order you see output from your shell scripts in is controlled by your OS's process scheduler and might as well be random. In the case where you redirect `tee`'s standard output to `/dev/null`, they both seem to follow the second scenario and set up the subprocesses before the parent `tee`'s redirection. This inconsistency on `bash`'s part does seem unusual and a potential source of subtle bugs.

I can't replicate the missing prompt issue, but that's with `bash` 4.4.20 - I don't have 5 installed on this computer.

Comment: Thank you (by up+1). Your **First** and **Second** answered my Q1 and Q2. However, regarding the output order, in Zsh, I can see the outputs come in the random order. But in Bash, no matter how I add the `sleep` in those scripts, the processes started in the order of `1-2-3` (we can see `xxx starts`) but the read stdin and output to stdout part come always in the order:`3-2-1`, `2.sh` waits `3.sh` finish then read from `/dev/stdin` Can you please cp the scripts and do some test in Bash, see if you can make the output in a different order? Thanks.

Comment: @Kent With a sleep in three.sh, I get random order for the XXX starts lines, but yeah, three two one for the rest.

Comment: Yes, that is what I don't understand. The `xxx starts` is dependent on where we put `sleep` obviously. It's not the question. But why and how the stdin blocking works here is what I want to know.

Comment: @Kent I haven't looked at the source, but I bet `tee` writes to its arguments in reverse order from how they appear on the command line (So right to left), and the scheduler just happens to immediately run the process that was blocking waiting for input after each write. Why the write to three apparently blocks while it's sleeping, now... (EDIT: Or not. Using `read` instead of that `cat` stuff results in random output order)

Comment: regarding the argument handling of the `tee`, I read the src of tee, I am not very good at C, but it seems that tee feeds the argument in this order: `stdout->file1->file2....fileN` don't get why the input was written from the right to left. :( https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tee.c#L237